# Maven does not update parent version with -Dmaven.local.repo from CLI

Tags: maven, command-line-interface

I am trying to update the version in a maven `pom.xml` that depends on a parent `pom.xml`.

I have `/pom.xml` that looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.burnian</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <!-- Plugins & other modules -->
</project>
```

And the child `/child/pom.xml` that looks like this (and is **not** a module in parent's pom).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>me.burnian</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.0</version>
        <!-- I've tried <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> with no success -->
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child</artifactId>

    <!-- Again other stuff I think irrelevant here -->
</project>
```

As you can see, child's `pom.xml` refers to version `13.0.0` of parent, which is now version `14.0.0`.
My goal is to update the version in the `parent` section to the correct version, using CLI only.

I've tried this sequence of commands which works properly and updates the parent version in the child's `pom.xml`:

```bash
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=14.0.0 # To update parent version
mvn clean install # To build parent module with new version
mvn -f child/pom.xml versions:update-parent -DparentVersion="[14.0.0]"
```

But whenever I try to implement it with `-Dmaven.repo.local`, the same process fails.

```bash
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=./.m2/ versions:set -DnewVersion=14.0.0
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=./.m2/ clean install
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=./.m2/ -f child/pom.xml versions:update-parent -DparentVersion="[14.0.0]"
```

The third command fails with `Could not find artifact me.burnian.parent:parent:pom:13.0.0 in Proxied-Maven`. I've tried adding `-DforceUpdate=true` but since I am not with a `RELEASE` or `LATEST` version (and can't use one), it has no effect.

Is there something I am missing? I've checked and there is indeed `me.burnian` with a `parent/14.0.0` folder in the `./.m2` repository, but the last command seems not to find it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just two notes: `<packaging>jar` is the default. You don't have to declare it explicitely. `<groupId>me.burnian.parent` is confusing since there's also a `child` in it. I'd call the group just `me.burnian`, containing `parent` and `child` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is chicken-egg problem:
in order to update parent version in `child/pom.xml` `versions:update-parent` need to initialise reactor, but it fails because there is no parent with previous version in local repository. If child were a submodule the `versions:update-child-modules` would help, in your case I believe the options are:

- install old version of parent first (`mvn clean install -N`)
- modify pom.xml using sed/awk/etc
- create new pom (e.g. `fakepom.xml`) with modules `parent` and `child` and run something like:

```
mvn -ffakepom.xml versions:set -DnewVersion=${newVersion} --pl parent
mvn -ffakepom.xml versions:update-child-modules
```

Comment: What troubles me is that it works when I do not specify `-Dmaven.repo.local=./.m2/`, and I feel like the problem is that the maven CLI cannot find my parent built with the new version (or even the previous) only when I specify a repository.

Comment: you may delete previous version of `parent` from local repository and get the same effect.